# Send php submit to MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am not the best at php but can get it to work, as my script sits it works but makes the database look like a mess. ill link a screenshot of how it submits and my code. Im trying to make it submit all data at once to 1 line(row) in my sql table but it runs each insert query once after the other as i have it making database a mess. how can i shorten this code up to make it do all the insert queries at once.

here is my php:

```
<?php

// send dataset 1
if (isset($_REQUEST['sendName'])) {

$yourfield=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]/','',$_REQUEST['sendName']);
$yourfield=htmlspecialchars($yourfield);

} else {
die('User did not send any data to be saved! field1');
}

$pdo_dsn='mysql:dbname=smsdata;host=localhost';
$pdo_user='root';     
$pdo_password='mypasswd';  

try {

$conn = new PDO($pdo_dsn, $pdo_user, $pdo_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$qry=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO SMSTable (sendName) VALUES (:sendName)');
$qry->execute(Array(":sendName" => $yourfield));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . " file: " . $e->getFile() . " line: " . $e->getLine();
exit;
}


// send dataset 2
if (isset($_REQUEST['sendNumber'])) {

$yourfield=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]/','',$_REQUEST['sendNumber']);
$yourfield=htmlspecialchars($yourfield);

} else {
die('User did not send any data to be saved! field2');
}

$pdo_dsn='mysql:dbname=smsdata;host=localhost';
$pdo_user='root';     
$pdo_password='mypasswd';  

try {

$conn = new PDO($pdo_dsn, $pdo_user, $pdo_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$qry=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO SMSTable (sendNumber) VALUES (:sendNumber)');
$qry->execute(Array(":sendNumber" => $yourfield));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . " file: " . $e->getFile() . " line: " . $e->getLine();
exit;
}


// send dataset 3
if (isset($_REQUEST['sendEmail'])) {

$yourfield=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\ ]/','',$_REQUEST['sendEmail']);
$yourfield=htmlspecialchars($yourfield);

} else {
die('User did not send any data to be saved! field3');
}

$pdo_dsn='mysql:dbname=smsdata;host=localhost';
$pdo_user='root';     
$pdo_password='mypasswd';  

try {

$conn = new PDO($pdo_dsn, $pdo_user, $pdo_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$qry=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO SMSTable (sendEmail) VALUES (:sendEmail)');
$qry->execute(Array(":sendEmail" => $yourfield));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . " file: " . $e->getFile() . " line: " . $e->getLine();
exit;
}
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

and here is what it does to the database it doesnt neatly put it on one line as i would like it makes it a mess as in screenshot, but does work just not as i need it to. http://prnt.sc/b7kum1  see in screenshot how it "steps" the data but i nee it across the top line all at once as it should be.

i know my code is horribly inefficient thats why im here :)

Comment: Execute *one* `INSERT` statement instead of *three*.

Comment: and how do i do that with my current code i tried combining them in the last section and it gives 500 error. tried making a new variable after all 3 sections to do that and it gives me php line error. i dont know how to pull the variables all together and insert all at once only one at a time, and it works but it makes the messy database.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `INSERT` it creates a new row, so you're inserting each parameter in a different row of the table. You should just insert one row with all 3 parameters.

```
$params = array();
foreach (array('sendName', 'sendNumber', 'sendEmail') as $field) {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$field])) {
        die("User didn't send $field");
    }
    $params[$field] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/','',$_REQUEST[$field]);
}

$pdo_dsn='mysql:dbname=smsdata;host=localhost';
$pdo_user='root';     
$pdo_password='mypasswd';  

try {

    $conn = new PDO($pdo_dsn, $pdo_user, $pdo_password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $qry=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO SMSTable (sendName, sendNumber, sendEmail) VALUES (:sendName, :sendNumber, :sendEmail)');
    $qry->execute($params);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . " file: " . $e->getFile() . " line: " . $e->getLine();
    exit;
}
```

I took out the call to `htmlentities`. That should be used when displaying data on a web page, not when storing in the database.

Comment: works perfect, thanks. i added the rest of my fields to it(didnt post full code) it would of been to long. got it working now.